# Syntax of regex

Tags: php, regex

I am curently developping a php program but I m have a problem: 
i have a string and would like to extract a part of it. So I try to use regex but it obviously doesnt work.
The code :

```php
<?php
  preg_match_all ( '#>+.+Direction+(.)+-+.+/th>#i', $chaine_de_caractere, $direction ); ?>
```

and a part of the string ;

```
    <th scope="row" class="direction-name"> Direction BLABLA1 - BLABLA2 </th>
<td class="departure-time">
    <span>15h30</span>
</td>
```

I just want to keep "BLABLA1".
So where is my error ?
thanks for reading
have a nice day

Comment: What you are trying to get?

Comment: You can also use this --> \>\s?Direction(.*)\-   here is an example ---> https://regex101.com/r/mRpbPX/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this `regex`

/`>\s*Direction\s*(.*?)\s*-`/

Answer (score 0):

Here is the one line answer to your question…

```
<?php
$direction=preg_match('#direction-name">\s*Direction\s*(.+)?\s*-\s.*?<*#i',
$chaine_de_caractere,$direction)?$direction[1]:'unknown';
echo $direction;
```